# probability of selecting all the correct options in a multiple select question(one or more may be correct)

Tags: probability

There are 4 options to a question of which one or more may be correct. If a student marks all the correct options then only it is considered as marked correctly. Suppose the student attempts this question randomly then what is the probability that it is correct?

Here is what I did:- Since the student has attempted the question this means it is not the case that all the four options are unselected. I made 4 mutually exclusive and exhaustive cases:-

case1) exactly one of the four option is correct

case2) exactly 2 are correct

case3) exactly 3 are correct

case4) exactly 4 are correct

case1)probability of being correct is: Select the only correct option and unselect every other option. Since for every option, he can either select it or unselect it. So the required probability is (select one with probability 1/2)*(unselect three with probability 1/8)*4= 4/16  { multiply with 4 because either of the option A,B,C,D can be correct}

case2) probability of being correct is: 6/16

case3)4/16

case4)1/16

So final answer=15/16.

I don't think there will be such high probability of correct selection in multiple select question.
The correct answer provided for this is 1/15. I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Kindly use $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we were to assume that each of the fifteen ($2^4-1$) possible non-empty subsets of selections are equally likely to be the correct answer and our person chooses randomly then the chance that our person picked the correct answer is simply $\dfrac{1}{15}$.

What you wound up calculating was not anything to do with the probability of our person as having picked the correct answer, but rather was the calculations that given each option was either needing to be selected or not uniformly at random and independent of all other selections, that the intended answer was non-empty.  Indeed, there are $16$ different subsets, one of which is empty and all others are non-empty.  That is however not what the question is asking for.

Comment: Wow. So there are 15 different sets of possible answers and only one will be correct, so 1/15. I didn't think that way. And thanks a lot for explaining my mistake as well.